# Border of a subset

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $(X, T)$ is a topological space.

We define the closure of $A \subset X$ as the minimal closed subset containing $A$ (which always exists by Zorn lemma) and denote it as $\overline{A}$.

We define the interior of $A \subset X$ as $X \setminus \overline{(X \setminus A)}$ and denote it as $Int(A)$ (alternatively, the interior can be described as the maximal open subset of $X$ that lies in $A$, the existence of which also follows from the Zorn lemma)

We define the border of $A \subset X$ as $\overline{A} \setminus Int(A)$ and denote it as $\delta A$.

Is it always true that $\forall A \subset X$ $Int(\delta A) = \emptyset$?

Comment: What is $X$? What is a random subset? What is an internal?

Comment: I think that the following is what you meant, correct me if I'm wrong. Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, let $A\subseteq X$. Then, is it true that $\mathrm{int}(\partial A)=\varnothing$ (where $\mathrm{int}$ denotes _interior_ and $\partial$ denotes _boundary_)?

Comment: Not true for general $A$. e.g., consider $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  As for random subsets - you need to define what you mean by random.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ topogical space and $A \subset X$. If $x \in \partial A$ then $ \forall U \in \mathcal{T} $ such that $x \in U$ we have $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $A^c \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Supose by contradiction that $x \in$ int$(\partial A)$ (open) then exist $V \in \mathcal{T}$, $x \in V$ and $V \subset \partial A$ clearly absurd.